# How to vizualize spring integration file in intellij idea 14?

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-integration

On the page https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/ it is said that Intellij Idea 14 has got a visual diagrams for spring integration.

But I can't find how to visualize my integration xml file.

(right click on file)/Diagrams/Show Diagram... shows a diagram with links between the beans. It is not very usefull.
[image]

Spring Integration Patterns plugin is enabled

I have Intellij Idea installed on a computer without access to the internet. May it be the reason why the diagrams are not working properly?

Comment: Right click on the application context file > Diagrams > Show Diagram > Spring Integration

Answer (score 4):

What do you want to see there?

For example.

We have `stomp-chat` sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/stomp-chat

And here is a diagram for this config: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/applications/stomp-chat/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/samples/chat/stomp/server/stomp-server.xml

[image]

I'd say that it is OK, however I agree that it would better if I'd provide `id` attribute for all components.

Of course, `Spring Integration Patterns` plugin has to be switched on.

Comment: Updated the question with screenshot of your file opened as a diagram

Comment: Yes, I also can open that type of diagram. But before that I have option to select - `Spring` or `Spring Integration`. Does your module in IDEA have `spring-integration-core` dependency ?

Comment: Yes I have spring-integration-core dependency

Comment: So, would be better to forward the question to IDEA forum: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/ideacommunity?view=discussions

Answer (score 1):

This link helps - https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5529839#5529839

"Please make sure the XML file is correctly configured in Spring context setup via Spring facet.
It requires spring-integration-core to be in module dependency of selected XML file."

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found that in addition to having the Spring facet enabled, and having the spring-integration-core dependency and having the relevant context file set as an application context under the facet, you also need to have just the containing module open. i.e. the stomp-chat spring-integration sample provides the "Spring Integration" diagram option if it is opened from its own pom.xml, however if you open the parent applications\pom.xml then the "Spring Integration" diagram option is not available, regardless of facets etc.

Comment: This is exactly what I experience with IDEA 15 and IDEA 2016.1. Can anyone answer if tried to generate spring integration diagram successfully out of sub module?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in a project where I use spring integration 2.1.4.

In a newer project I use 4.0.0 and there Intellij Idea offers the option to open the spring integration diagram.

Perhaps that is the reason and you "only" need a newer version of spring integration.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the newer versions of Intellij create separate modules per source set by default which somehow ends up conflicting with earlier setups. Using Intellij 2016.1, I instead reimported my project with the following options checked:

[image: Gradle Import options]

Once I did that then (right click on file)/Diagrams/Show Diagram once again gave me the Spring Integration Option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, click on your **Spring Integration context file > Diagrams > Show Diagram... > Spring Integration.**, but if you haven't this menu follow below:

1. You should have identified integration context as Spring **XML based configurations**. Instruction here : [Create a Intellij file set](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/managing-file-sets.html#create_file_set)
2. I don't know why, but I had a problem with Spring Integration Diagram when I installed **Springirun** plugin.